# System.Net.Http - Could not load file or assembly, then Cannot load a reference assembly for execution

Tags: c#, .net

When I publish a csproj I get the message:

Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http

If I add it to the project and republish, I get the message:

[BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http'

So it's like catch-22

This is the system.web of my web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: If present try delete the "System.Net.Http.dll" (or the dll that need that namespace) from bin\Release folder, after that it should work.

Comment: Is this on your local machine or on the published environment? Is this .NET Core? What version of .NET?

Comment: Mh... i was thinking about my environment, but the dll should be in the publish environment too, maybe not in the same folder.

Comment: Remove the file from the project.  It looks like the file was added to the project.  I would open the .proj file with Notepad and see where the Http is found.

Comment: Thanks for the replies; this is happening on the published environment; I've added to my original post my web.config's system.web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first:

Make sure all your projects are pointing at the same version of System.Net.Http, you can manually verify this by checking your `bin` folder after a compile. Just make sure the DLLs are the same version.

Then
Make sure all your App.Config/Web.Config have a binding redirect

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Lastly make sure you are not accidently publishing a 32-bit DLL with an 64-bit executable. This will also cause the `BadImageFormatException`.

Check your project settings to make sure you are targetting the right environment, then check your dependencies to make sure they are not accidently pulling/publishing the wrong DLL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Lastly make sure you are not accidently publishing a 32-bit DLL with an 64-bit executable. This will also cause the BadImageFormatException"?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by install .Net framework 4.7.2  from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054531/microsoft-net-framework-4-7-2-web-installer-for-windows